# Autocorrelation with Groupby in Pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, autocorrelation

I am using Python to process a panel data set. The dataframe looks like

```
stock     date     time   spread  
 VOD      01-01    9:05    0.01          
 VOD      01-01    9:12    0.03        
 VOD      01-01   10:04    0.02          
 VOD      01-01   10:15    0.01        
 VOD      01-01   10:25    0.03       
 VOD      01-01   11:04    0.02     
 VOD      01-02    9:04    0.02     
 ...       ...     ...     ....    
 BAT      01-01    13:05   0.04    
 BAT      01-02    9:07    0.05    
 BAT      01-02    9:10    0.06
```

I intend to get the stock-day autocorrelation table of spread to be

```
stock     date    autocorrelation
 VOD      01-01       0.52          
 VOD      01-02       0.32    
 BAT      01-01       0.23  
 BAT      01-02       0.54
 ...       ...        ...
```

I have tried

`want=df.groupby(['stock','date'])['spread'].autocorr(lag=1)`

However, the system gave me :

`AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'autocorr' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method.`

It seems I cannot use `Groupby` and `autocorr` functions together.

Comment: The suggestion in the error message is a good one.  `df.groupby(['stock','date'])['spread'].apply(pd.Series.autocorr, lag=1)`

Comment: Hi @piRSquared ,  Thanks it works. now I have some minor issues with indexing . Could you advise how to get output I posted above ? Thanks again.

Comment: `df.groupby(['stock','date'])['spread'].apply(pd.Series.autocorr).reset_index(name='autocorrelation')`

Comment: thanks. Really appreciated.  Or I can use `want= want.reset_index(drop=False)`